# SSL Certificate - Self-Signed Certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, postfix, ubuntu-14.04, pci-dss

I'm trying to get PCI compliant and the PCI scanning company is showing below Fail scan report

> SL Certificate - Self-Signed Certificate SSL Certificate - Self-Signed
>   Certificate port 25/tcp over SSL
>
> IMPACT: By exploiting this vulnerability, an attacker can launch a
>   man-in-the-middle attack. 
>   SOLUTION: Please install a server
>   certificate signed by a trusted third-party Certificate Authority.
>   RESULT: Certificate #0
>   CN=ip-172-31-27-94.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal is a self signed
>   certificate.

But I already purchased third party SSL certificate and works well over port 443.

How to resove this for port 25 ?

> root@www:/etc/apache2# netstat -tapen | grep ":25" tcp        0      0
>   0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9610        1284/master tcp6       0      0 :::25
>   :::*                    LISTEN      0          9611        1284/master

Comment: you're not describing the webserver config you have... if you look at it from the outside, try openssl s_client to get the certificate details, and match them to what you have in the cert store, then you know which certificate is offered as a starting point.

Comment: @FlorenzKley This is not a webserver, it's an SMTP server.

Comment: openssl s_client works against SMTP servers, too :-)

Answer (score -1):

Install the same third party certificate in your Postfix email server. The configuration file is /etc/postfix/main.cf

Comment: I have updated same certs in postfix main.cf but now what to do for this new error `SSL Server Allows Anonymous Authentication Vulnerability` on same 25 port ?